# Scala's parser combinator: parse an option

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Say I have a parser like this:

```
trait PT {}

trait StatementPT extends PT{}

...

class LoopConditionPT(val operation: String, val variable: IdentPT, val condition: Option[(String,ExpressionPT)]) extends StatementPT { ... }
```

The `Option[(String,ExpressionPT)])` bug me for a day, I mean I can deal with `Option[T]`, but `Option[(T,T)]`? I wrote this `def loopCondition` but it always raises error:

```
def loopCondition: Parser[LoopConditionPT] = "some string" ~ var ~ opt(("TIL"|"WILE") ~ expression) ^^ {
  case a ~ b ~ Some(c ~ d) => new LoopCondition(a, b, Option[(c, d)])
  case a ~ b ~ None => new LoopCondition(a, b, Option[("None", -1)])
```

Can someone help me fixes the `loopCondition`? Thanks.

Comment: Thats not a valid syntax... Instead of `Option[(c,d)]` write `Option(c -> d)`,`Option((c,d))`,`Some(c -> d)`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` are used for denoting types. When you want to create an `Option` - i.e. call `Option.apply()` - use parenthesis instead of square brackets. So instead of

```
new LoopCondition(a, b, Option[(c, d)])
```

say

```
new LoopCondition(a, b, Option((c, d)))
```

or you can use syntactic sugar for tuples and say

```
new LoopCondition(a, b, Option(c -> d))
```